# Redirect to old website version when not found

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a website (ex. at chamthi.net).
I lance new version of the website, and old version (articles) has been moved to **/old** directory (**chamthi.net/old**).
I want each time a user go to a url that is currently not available (404), the website will redirect user to old version.
Is there any solution for that?
Thanks.

Comment: maybe an http 301 or 302 or 303?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom 404 error page, with dynamic content adding /old to referrer address and redirecting to it...